# Android view in Android studio says "nothing to show", can't run app anymore either

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried some things with vcs, git, not sure what I did. Suddenly my Android view says nothing to show:
[image: Android View]

However here's my Project view showing everything correctly:

[image: Project View]

I also can't run my app anymore, it prompts me with run configurations. 
[image: Run configurations dialog]

No idea what I did wrong.

Edit: I fixed it, luckily I backed up the project beforehand, simply replaced the whole folder of the project with the backed up folder.

Answer (score 6):

When this happens, check your **settings.gradle(Project Settings)** file in **Gradle Scripts**, ensure that file has the following line;

```
include ":app"
```

Comment: where "app" is your app name.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, luckily I backed up the project beforehand, simply replaced the whole folder of the project with the backed up folder.

Answer (score 0):

Click on gradle tab in android studio.Now you can see your project name in opened window ; click on it and let to gradle build running. :)